# Rdrobust: error message with small bandwidths and bandwidth selector

Tags: r, regression

We use monthly data on health outcomes, the running variable is month of birth (discrete). Currently we are experimenting with a maximum bandwith of 12 months and a minimum of 1 month. The dependent variable is an integer ranging between 0 and 60. There are no missing values and the number of observations is about 285,000 almost equally distributed across the running variable.

**Problematic specifications:**

- Any specification (independent from kernel and polynomial choice) with a bandwidth smaller or equal to 3 (`h<=3`) do not work (e.g. `rdrobust(data$y, data$x, c=0, kernel=”triangular”, h=3, all=TRUE)`)
- For higher polynomials (`p>=3`) and epanechnikov kernel, bandwidths smaller or equal to 6 (`h<=6`) do not work
- For polynomial `p=4` and epanechnikov or triangular kernel, bandwidths smaller or equal to 6 (`h<=6`) do not work
- The bandwidth selector (`rdbwselect`) does not work for any specification or kernel

Error message that occurs in all those cases:

> “Error in chol.default(crossprod(x)): the leading minor of order 3 is not positive definite”

The only thing that changes in the error message across specifications is the order of the leading minor, e.g. for `h=3` it’s 3, for `h=6` it’s etc.

**Already taken attempts to solve the problem:**

- Manually reduced the bandwidth in the sample (e.g. only kept observations 3 months before and after the cutoff) and then let the specification run on full bandwidth --> same error message
- By using “(`options(error=recover)`) went into the Code of the package and detected the problematic matrix:

  - For `rdrobust(data$y, data$x, c=0, kernel=”triangular”, h=3, all=TRUE)` it’s the matrix in line 285 (`sqrt(W_b_r)*R_q_r`) which is not positive definite and thus not invertible
  - As far as I understand this matrix is independent from `y` but influenced by `x` (running variable) and the choices of the kernel and the bandwidth. So the problem might be caused the running variable but I don’t understand what the problem with the running variable exactly is.
  - For `rdbwselect(data$y, data$x)` it’s the matrix in `rdrobust(Y_l. X_l, T_l, Z_l, C_l, fw_l, c=c, o=q+1, nu=q+1, o_b=q+2, h_v=c_bw,h_B=range_l, 0, vce, nnmat)` in line 18 (`R_V*sqrt(eW)`) which is not positive definite and thus not invertible
  - Also here it seems as the matrix is not influenced by `y`, but by `x`

I hope my description of the problem is understandable. Does anyone have an idea what the root of the problem could be and how I could solve it?

Please let me know if I can provide you with any more information.

Comment: Small edits. OP has done a good job to try and explain the issues, including mathematical and technical details.  This post would benefit from comments from potential answerers asking questions to clarify things.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Might it be related to the running variable being sparse and unbalanced?